# SQL Server Performance Issues with very simple query (Straight SQL, ADO.Net, Entity Framework)

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, ado.net

I've got a very interesting issue currently with a very simple query:

```
SELECT TOP 2 ID, StoreID, UserID, Lat, Long 
FROM EntityLocation 
WHERE UserID = 'NS4089'
```

This query (in Enterprise Manager) runs in < 1 ms timed using:

```
SELECT GETDATE();

SELECT TOP 2 ID, StoreID, UserID, Lat, Long 
FROM EntityLocation 
WHERE UserID = 'NS4089';

SELECT GETDATE();
```

The data returned is:

```
3196    NULL    NS4089  -33.720801  151.019014    (so not big at all)
```

The table schema is:

- ID (PK, int not null)
- StoreID (int, null)
- UserID (nvarchar(50), null)
- Lat (nvarchar(50), not null)
- Long (nvarchar(50), not null)

Using ADO.Net this query takes 213ms:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection("connection_string")) {
    var start = DateTime.Now;

    var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 2 ID, StoreID, UserID, Lat, Long FROM EntityLocation WHERE UserID='NS4089'", conn);

    conn.Open();

    var reader = command.ExecuteReader();

    while (reader.Read()) 
        Console.WriteLine("\t{0}\t{1}\t{2}", reader[0], reader[1], reader[2]);

    Console.WriteLine($"\nQuery Took: {DateTime.Now.Subtract(start).TotalSeconds}s\n");        
  }
```

Using a custom query in Entity Framework, the query takes 1642ms:

```
var start = DateTime.Now;

var e = db.EntityLocation.SqlQuery("SELECT TOP 2 * FROM EntityLocation WHERE UserID='NS4089'").Single();

Console.WriteLine($"\nQuery Took: {DateTime.Now.Subtract(start).TotalSeconds}s\n");
```

Using the generated (DB first) classes the query takes: 2746ms

```
var start = DateTime.Now;
db.EntityLocation.Single(r => r.UserID == "NS4089");        
Console.WriteLine($"\nQuery Took: {DateTime.Now.Subtract(start).TotalSeconds}s\n");
```

My question is how is it possible that:

- ADO.Net takes > 200ms to run the query and transfer such a small amount 
  of data.  Latency could explain this the DB is in the cloud, so lets assume 200ms is ok.  I could test further but this is not the big issue
- Entity Framework is so slow.....  Logging out the queries run by EF it says that it executes in 50ms.  But my timing returns > 2 seconds

I have tried disabling lazy loading, change detection, etc, nothing improves this performance.

Any hints/pointers to this one, its driving me nuts.

Comment: This isn't a solution especially where it may not be an option, but the performance weirdness with EF is why I switched to dapper dot net.

Comment: +1 for Dapper. It has saved me probably hundreds of hours of these sorts of headaches and weirdness.  You write your query exactly how you want it to run, it handles everything else for you, and it's _fast_.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type) - you should always use the most appropriate data type - that's what they're there for, after all! So why on earth do you store **decimal** values for latitude and longitude as `nvarchar(50)` ????

Comment: @marc_s dataypes were chosen due to application requirements. and they have nothing to do with the performance issues as this has been tested.